# Тормоза в консоле и некорых GUI посте замены видеокарты RTX 3050, Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

Сегодня заменил видеокарту GTX650Ti -> RTX3050

Драйвера переустановил, все как полагается. В Блендере заметил разницу сразу, т.е. рендер стал шустрее. Т.е. с видеокартой все оК.

Но в консоли, в частности `mc` стал жутко тупить. Если кликнуть на файл, то его выделение занимает секунды три. Так же  "неуверенно" перемещается стрелками.
В редакторе `xed` тормоза при наборе текста для `.bashrc` Но, для других, даже длинных xml файлов такого нет. Сами символы еще ничего, но, конкретно пробел, секунды три. И неуверенно работает перемещение стрелками, Home, End.`mousepad` работает без тормозов. Сейчас, тоже при наборе вопроса, тормозов нет.
Память, проц не перегружены. Видеопамять также в норме.

Только что попробовал зайти под новым пользователем. Все летает, как и нужно.

Comment: Драйвера открытые (nouveau) или проприетарные? Сеанс X11/Xorg или Wayland?

Comment: @andreymal Xorg, проприентарные. Иначе куда не работает

Comment: @andreymal под другим пользователем все летает, тормозов нету

Comment: @andreymal, проблема решилась. Она была в оконном менеджере compton